# Paste the text in input box when clicked on drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a **dropdown** when I click on them I would like the text to paste in the input box having  **class = paste**. This is what I have done so far

**index.php**

```
<select>
    <option class="others">Option 1</option>
    <option class="others">Option 2</option>
</select>
<input class="paste" disabled="disabled" autocomplete="off" type="text">
```

**Jquery.js**

```
$(document).on('click', '.others', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.paste').val($(this).text());
});
```

Here is a fiddle [Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/kunz/0rxqrmrz/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `change` event instead of `click`

```
<select id="someSelect">
   <option class="others">Option 1</option>
   <option class="others">Option 2</option>
 </select>

$(function() {
    $("#someSelect").change(function() {
        alert( $('option:selected', this).text() );
        $('.paste').val($('option:selected', this).text());
    });
});
```

For [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qoxhorwb/)

Comment: Change Property or Event?

Comment: This worked fine for me thanks for the quick help lol didnt think of that makes sense thou adding the change event :) thanks

Comment: Glad it worked, accept the answer, so others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('change', '.others1', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.paste').val($('option:selected', this).text());
});


<select class='others1'>
  <option class="others">Option 1</option>
  <option class="others">Option 2</option>
  <option class="others">Option 3</option>
  <option class="others">Option 4</option>
</select>
<input class="paste" disabled="disabled" autocomplete="off" type="text">
```

[DEMO](https://fiddle.jshell.net/0rxqrmrz/1/)

1. Add a class on the select
2. Use change
3. Use $('option:selected',this)

Comment: @jake123 glad to help mate you can check the demo to see the code in action :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this [**FIDDLE**](https://fiddle.jshell.net/0rxqrmrz/3/).

Since you are using jquery not forget to call jquery library.

**HTML**

```
<select class="others">
   <option value="">select</option>
   <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
   <option class="Option 2">Option 2</option>
   <option class="Option 3">Option 3</option>
   <option class="Option 4">Option 4</option>
 </select>
 <input class="paste" disabled="disabled"  autocomplete="off" type="text">
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".others").change(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $('.paste').val($(this).val());
   });
});
```